# World position into local position

Tags: unity, mathematics, rotation, position

I want to understand how I can convert world position of an object into local position. Especially how to deal with a rotation of objects.

I'm testing transform.InverseTransform(...) methods. When parent and child has 0 rotation, this methods easily convert world into local position. I don't know how to deal with a situation, when one of the objects has not zero rotation.

In the example below my parent object has (0,0,10) position and (0,0,0) rotation. Child position (0,0,0) and rotation (90,0,0).

```cs
Debug.Log (string.Format ("World position: {0}\nLocalPosition: {1}\nInverseTransformPoint: {2}\nInverseTransformVector: {3}\nInverseTransformDirection: {4}\nTransformPoint: {5}\nTransformVector: {6}\nTransformDirection: {7}",
transform.position.ToString (),
transform.localPosition.ToString (),
transform.InverseTransformPoint (transform.position).ToString (),
transform.InverseTransformVector (transform.position).ToString (),
transform.InverseTransformDirection (transform.position).ToString (),
transform.TransformPoint (transform.localPosition).ToString (),
transform.TransformVector (transform.localPosition).ToString (),
transform.TransformDirection (transform.localPosition).ToString ()));
```

The example debug result:

```
World position: (-1.0, -0.7, 10.0)
LocalPosition: (-1.0, -0.7, 0.0)
InverseTransformPoint: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
InverseTransformVector: (-1.0, 10.0, 0.7)
InverseTransformDirection: (-1.0, 10.0, 0.7)
TransformPoint: (-2.1, -0.7, 9.3)
TransformVector: (-1.0, 0.0, -0.7)
TransformDirection: (-1.0, 0.0, -0.7)
```

What should I add to transform.InverseTransformPoint (transform.position) to get transform.localPosition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should I add to transform.InverseTransformPoint (transform.position) to get transform.localPosition?

Add `parent`:

```
transform.parent.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position) == transform.localPosition
```

`transform.localPosition` is the position of this object in its *parent's* coordinate system.

`transform.InverseTransformPoint()` transforms a position from world space into *this* object's coordinate system. So naturally when you take the worldspace position of this object's origin and transform it into *its own* coordinate system, you get zero - that's what "origin" means.